# How will I maximize the imageView once the image is clicked on the ListView?

Tags: android, image, listview, android-listview, fullscreen

I have a listview, If the image is clicked on the listview I want it to be seen in a fullscreen

here is my code: that is when the listview is being clicked

```
ImageList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {

                String Userid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.user_id)).getText().toString();
                String ScrapBookId = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.photo_id)).getText().toString();
                // ---Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FullImageActivity.class);

                in.putExtra("userid", Userid);
                in.putExtra("IMAGE",ScrapBookId);

                // ---starting new activity and expecting some response back
                startActivityForResult(in, 100);
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), eventId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
```

then it will turn into the FullImageActivity here is the code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.fullimage);
        int imgid = getIntent().getIntExtra("IMAGE", 0);
        ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.photo_id);
        img.setImageResource(imgid);
        txt.setText(imgid);
 }
}
```

but I think there is no image passed :( how will I do it? please help me :( Thank you

Comment: you pass image id but if there is no image then pass -1 and detect here and check if you get -1 then you show only default image.

Answer (score 0):

You have added a **String** extra with the key `"IMAGE"` in the first activity. In the second activity you are trying to obtain it with `getIntExtra("IMAGE", 0)`. There is no int extra with this key, hence this call will return zero.

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but in any case the type of extra you are trying to obtain should match the type that you added to the intent.

Answer (score 0):

There is no image passed to the new Activity.  Your image identifier is a String ("ScrapBookId") but you are treating it as a resource Identifier (Integer) in the OnCreate.

Assuming your drawables are resources (which they appear to be), record the resourceId you set for each imageView as follows:

```
    iv.setTag(R.drawable.ponies);
```

Then in the onItemClick, lookup the resourceId:

```
    ImageView iv = ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageview1));
    int resId = (Integer) iv.getTag();

    in = new Intent(...)
    in.putExtra("IMAGE", resId);
```

Then in the onCreate:

```
    resId = getIntent().getIntExtra("IMAGE", 0);
    img.setImageResource(resId);
```